# Use System.Drawing.Color to set background and foreground in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

How can I set background and foreground properties of WPF textblocks,  using a System.Drawing.Color programmatically ? A solution without a converter would be nice.

```
System.Drawing.Color BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
System.Drawing.Color ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

TextBlock txt = new TextBlock ();
txt.Background=BackColor ;
txt.ForeGround=ForeColor ;
```

> PS: The color I would be assigining would be from a windows forms app
>   and hence it would be a System.Drawing.Color not a
>   System.Windows.Media.Color as required by WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```
System.Drawing.Color BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

txt.Background = new SolidColorBrush(
    Color.FromArgb(BackColor.A, BackColor.R, BackColor.G, BackColor.B));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a `Brush` rather than an `Color`.

There are several predefined brushes so you could do this:

```
txt.Background = Brushes.Black;
txt.Foreground = Brushes.White;
```

[MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However, as you are reading the colour from a Windows Form App then you'll have to create your `Brush` from the component colours:

```
txt.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(BackColor.A, BackColor.R, BackColor.G, BackColor.B));
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I thought specifying System.Drawing.Color and not System.Windows.Media.Color was enough. Anyways sorry for confusion. Upvoted your answer. Can't mark two answers as answered. You did answer it though.